# How do I find the regular function and the point where the tangent line will be at?

Tags: calculus, limits

If I am given the expression $lim_{h\to 0}\frac{2^{3+h}-2^3}{h}$, how do I find what $g(x)$ (or the regular function) is and what point we are evaluating the slope at (or where the tangent line will touch the curve of $g(x)$)? Online problems tend to create the limit expression using the regular function and point of the tangent rather than creating the regular function and point of the tangent from the limit expression. So I don't really know how to approach this problem. Could someone outline their step by step process to solving problems like these, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have there: $$L=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{2^{3+h}-2^3}{h}$$ is the derivative of the the function $f(x)=2^x$ at $x=3$. Thus, this limit $L$ calculates the slope of the tangent line to $f(x)$ at $x=3$.

Your tangent line is given by $$y-f(3)=L(x-3)$$

Comment: What steps did you take to get to your conclusion that $f(x)$ is $2^x$ and that $x=3$?

Comment: But how did you know $y=2^x$? That's what I am confused about.

Comment: Sorry if its sound like a stupid question but how did you know to plug in $2^x$ though? I get that it works when you plug in $y=2^x$ but how would I even know to begin with $2^x$?